# Update widget on Android O

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-8.0-oreo, android-implicit-intent

My app does not receive ACTION_SCREEN_ON or ACTION_USER_PRESENT on Android O device after device remains idle for some time. 
My app has widgets. I update those widgets with data from backend when the user unlocks the phone. This functionality has been working when I am targetting SDK 25. 
Now I am compiling the app with target SDK 26. I converted the service that gets data for widgets to JobService. Everythings works fine when the user adds the widget to the home screen. Then if I kill the app and turn off the screen and say after 5 minutes if I unlock my phone, my app receives ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_USER_PRESENT intent I am able to start the service and update data on the widget. However, If I leave device idle for a couple of hours and then when I unlock the screen, the application does not receive ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_USER_PRESENT intent. 
Is this due to Android O limitations on implicit intents. If so how have you solved the problem?
If not then what method has worked for you?

Comment: "Is this due to Android O limitations on implicit intents" -- most likely, as I do not see them on [the whitelist](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html).

Comment: But then it does not explain....app receiving intents even after I have killed the app for first 5 to 10 minutes. Updating widget on "screen on" is probably the common pattern. What would be the solution?

Comment: Other than doing the work periodically, rather than based on those specific events, I do not have a solution for you. I also cannot explain the difference in the implicit `Intent` behavior that you are seeing. IMHO, they should have those two broadcasts on the whitelist.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem. I'm also facing similar issue. I want to update my app widget whenever the user unlocks his device.

Comment: Looking for a solution too. It works for a while, but then stops.

Comment: What solutions brothers?